# Lookupvalue for a Search String in Tabular Model

Tags: dax, lookup, ssas-tabular

Seeking assistance with Tabular Model DAX query.

I've a Lookup/Reference table which provides the Sport Items and Sports related to it.
Like

```
SPORT_ITEM             SPORT
_____________________________
BaseballBAT           Baseball
BASEBALL BAT          Baseball
Baseball Glove        Baseball
Helmet                Football
Shoulderpads          Football
Shoulder Pads         Football
```

Then I have a table which has descriptive column. Like

```
ITEM_DESCRIPTION
__________________
Baseballbat Needed
Baseball Bat required
Helmet wanted
ShoulderPads provided
Shoulder Pads needed
```

What I've been asked to do is -
Lookup the value under ITEM_DESC and to the sting matching SPORT_ITEM and return SPORT name column.

So I should see

```
ITEM_DESCRIPTION            SPORT
__________________________________
Baseballbat Needed          Baseball
Baseball Bat required       Baseball
Helmet wanted               Football
ShoulderPads provided       Football
Shoulder Pads needed        Football
```

Note:

- Unfortunately there is no relationship between the 2 tables. This
  lookup is the only way to join.
- I cannot do this join in the data source because I'm not allowed by the DBAs. Long story, (you didnt hear me say red tape).

Since there is no join, I cannot use Related, right?
And since this is Tabular Model, there is no CONTAINSVALUE.

Please let me know how this can be achieved.

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: have you tried LOOKUPVALUE you use it when RELATED is not an option https://dax.guide/lookupvalue/

Comment: Thanks @Jon. Yes I tried it. However, It is looking up the full value in the ITEM_DESCRIPTION column. I may have values in there which would read ```Baseballbat``` only. These it can pick. It does not read where ITEM_DESCRIPTION says ```Baseballbat wanted``` . I'lI need to look for a part of the string. And lookup where it matches. 
I tried using SEARCH along with LOOKUPVALUE, in 3rd argument. But I cannot because for SEARCH the lookup table is out of scope. it will only read from the table it is used in.

Answer (score 0):

For those who may stumble upon similar issue -

After a lot of reading everywhere, found the below link and especially in comments.

A combination of a various solutions in comments helped.

[Info](https://p3adaptive.com/2014/01/containsx-finding-if-a-value-in-table-1-has-a-matching-value-in-table-2/)